# Firebase Authentication JS does not populate `providerData`array

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

in a VueJS / QuasarJS application Im using `firebase-js-sdk` [1] together with `firebaseui-web` [2] to handle authentication.

After successful auth with any of the configured providers (e.g. password, google, apple, etc) I want to check which provider the user used. But immediately after successful authentication the `user.providerData[]` array that should contain the information is empty.

**BUT** if I reload my app the `user.providerData[]` array is suddenly populated correctly.

I´m checking for user data with something like this

```js
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser;

if (user) {
  console.log(user.providerData)
}
```

After that the `user` object is fully populated (incl auth tokens, etc) but the `user.providerData[]` array is empty. Only after a page reload (CTRL-R) does the array get populated.

I searched both projects issues pages and documentation and didnt find anything that could explain this.

Im thankful for ANY idea where to look next!

**EDIT**

As suggested by @aside Im using `onAuthStateChanged` to check for updates of the user state.

```js
  onAuthStateChanged(
    fbAuth,
    (user) => {
      if (user) {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged: user found");
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged: user.providerData", user.providerData);
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged: user", user);
      } else {
        console.log("onAuthStateChanged: no user found");
      }
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log("onAuthStateChanged:", error);
    }
  );
```

But even if I wait minutes after authentication is completed, still the user.providerData array is only populated after a page reload.

Here is a full demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/perelin/firebase-auth-providerdata-test

Thanks in advance :)

Im using

```js
    "firebase": "9.6.1",
    "firebaseui": "6.0.0",
```

[1] https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk
[2] https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web

Comment: If i were you i would dump `firebase ui` library it has 145 opened issues. Firebase library already provide really easy to use functions.

Comment: Actually thought about that. Project crew is also pretty unresponsive and stubborn on some issues. But for now they provide me 80% of the functionality I need with very little implementation effort. Since its a hobby project on my side I dont want to rebuild the whole UI stuff myself. So for now I will stay with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app should call [`getAuth().currentUser.reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#reload) to refresh the local user data after login.

This could be done either in [`beforeRouteEnter()` nav guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) of the `LoggedIn` view:

```js
// LoggedIn.vue
import { getAuth, signOut } from "firebase/auth";

export default {
  async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    await getAuth().currentUser?.reload() 
    next()
  },
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/refresh-user-data-on-login-via-nav-guard-drkmq?file=/src/components/LoggedIn.vue)

Or in the [`onAuthStateChanged` callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged):

```js
// main.js
onAuthStateChanged(
  fbAuth,
  async (user) => {
    await user?.reload() 
  },
)
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/refresh-user-data-on-login-via-onauthstatechanged-callback-rtn94?file=/src/components/LoggedIn.vue)

Comment: Wow, this works. Thanks @tony19 But Im still a bit confused, maybe you can help me out: Whats the "?" for after `user?` or `currentUser?`? And where in the docs did I miss this mechanic? I had the impression I was reading the firebase auth docs from back to back and I have not seen a "before you access things in `user` you must `reload()`"

Comment: If somebody else is wondering about the "?" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 1):

Your code is only running once instead of running every time the auth state is updated.
If you want to listen to any changes to the auth state, use a callback along with `onAuthStateChanged` as described here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // Check used provider here
    const providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

The reason checking/requesting the user object right after authentication does not work is that it might take firebase a second to update the `providerData` array. `signInWithX` might therefore return before the property is updated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the approach but it did not seem to resolve my issue. To encapsulate my problem I am prototyping a minimal implementation but got stuck on something else. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70007904/firebase-auth-with-firebaseui-web-does-not-redirect-after-authentication

Comment: I updated the question with a demo repository. Still no idea whats going on here.