# Firebase Auth with firebaseui-web does not redirect after authentication

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Im currently prototyping VueJS based a sign-in flow with Firebase Auth and the web widget library firebaseui-web.

After successful authentication (either `password` or `google` provider) the widget loading bar is endlessly repeating and firebaseui-web does not fire its `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback. But the network calls to `identitytoolkit.googleapis.com` clearly seem to have my user identified and authenticated (see screenshot)

[image: POST calls to identitytoolkit.googleapis.com]

The config object looks like this:

```js
const uiConfig = {
  signInSuccessUrl: "#/loggedin",
  signInOptions: [
    EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
  ],
  tosUrl: "http://example.com",
  privacyPolicyUrl: "http://example.com",
  signInFlow: "redirect",
  callbacks: {
    signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult, redirectUrl) {
      console.log("signInSuccessWithAuthResult:", authResult, redirectUrl);
      return true;
    },
    uiShown: function () {
      console.log("uiShown");
    },
  },
};
```

VUeJS code:

```js
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data: function () {
    return {
      fbUI: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    initFBUI: function () {
      const uiReference = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance("demoUI");
      console.log("uiReference ", uiReference);
      this.fbUI =
        uiReference !== null
          ? uiReference
          : new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(this.$fbAuth, "demoUI");
      console.log("this.fbUI", this.fbUI);
    },
    startAuthUI: function () {
      console.log("ui.isPendingRedirect()", this.fbUI.isPendingRedirect());
      this.fbUI.start("#firebaseui-auth-container", uiConfig);
      console.log("this.fbUI started");
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initFBUI();
    this.startAuthUI();
  },
};
```

Reproduceable demo and full code is under https://github.com/perelin/firebase-auth-providerdata-test.

Here is the CodeSandbox for this rep: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/perelin/firebase-auth-providerdata-test (sometimes it throws a `Unexpected token '{'` error. Then just reload / rebuild the page.

I would be thankful for any idea what to try next!

Comment: Could you please provide the code in a codesandbox instead of sharing a repo? That would work a lot faster than cloning and building your repo.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Here is the CodeSandbox for this rep: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/perelin/firebase-auth-providerdata-test (sometimes it throws a `Unexpected token '{'` error. Then just reload the page / rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the issue. It seems that the firebaseui instance returned by `firebaseui.auth.AuthUI` does not like to be a Vue data property [1]

Would love to know why, but the bug hunt cost me enough energy. Im done :)

Here is my fix for that https://github.com/perelin/firebase-auth-providerdata-test/commit/e8c31aecb4d3bc8bcd93928c55c439201a965c65

[1] https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html